# Espresso machine stops working after making 2 cups

Tags: espresso-machine

I've had the DeLonghi EC680 for about a year now. It is still working, but there is something wrong with it. It is able to make two cups of coffee in a row, but when I am trying to make the third one, the noise from the machine becomes quieter and no coffee is coming out. Then, when I turn off the machine for a bit and try again, it works just fine. I descaled it recently and cleaned the filter, but the problem is still there. What could be the problem and what could I do to fix it? Thanks for any help.

Comment: Maybe it needs servicing? I don't think we have enough information to really diagnose the problem.

Answer (score 1):

A machine turning itself off and working fine after a resting period sounds like a protective mechanism jumping in. If pulling multiple cups was fine in the past and now isn’t, it seems like some piece of the inner machinery gets too hot, and lime scale may or may not be the explanation. If you have a particular heavy buildup, it’s possible that one regular descaling cycle has been not strong enough to fully break down the deposits.

My first step would be to run the descaling at least once more and if possible extend the “soaking” time. That should also deal with particles floating in the system that were loosened in the first descaling and may now have wandered around and create a blockage. Rinse well afterwards, not only to get rid of the acidic cleaner, but also because of lime scale chips.

If that doesn’t help, it’s time to contact a repair service.

Answer (score 0):

It is not uncommon for small particles of scale to clog the tubes. It sounds like this might be happening.
Taking it apart for cleaning and to check for scale is a good option.